# Asterisk 1.8 BLF Subscription for External Program

Tags: sip, asterisk, asteriskami

We're running Asterisk version 1.8.4.2 and I'm looking to create a server application that will allow several client programs to check on the "presence" of specific extensions, among other things.  I understand that the AMI will allow me to poll this information, however I was hoping there might be a way to give the server an extension and subscribe it to the extensions in question to avoid having to poll the AMI constantly.

It seems like I might have to implement the SIP protocol into my server if BLF were the route I wanted to take.  Is there a better and simpler solution that I've managed to overlook in my research?

Comment: Try the [asterisk-users mailing list](http://lists.digium.com/mailman/listinfo/asterisk-users).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement these approaches:

1. AMI event hook and digging in incoming events
2. Make your application subscribing on notifies on extension status changes via SIP notifies
3. Make your asterisk publishing extensions status with XMPP